# Use mongodb replica sets as broker Celery

Tags: mongodb, celery

I am a beginner in Celery. I need to use MongoDB replica sets as broker. I am using celery 5.2.3.

Also, is there any issues with using replica sets as broker in celery 5.2.3 ?

Comment: Do you really have to? MongoDB backend is experimental as far as I know. Even if it is not considered experimental anymore it is most likely far from Redis and RabbitMQ one in terms of stability and performance. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Actually working with mongodb was fine till a necessity to use the replica sets came up. I do not know whether this issue is with only celery 5.2.3 or an issue which has been encountered before with any workaround as a solution available.Hence raised the question.Currently am not able to use mongodb replica sets as broker with celery 5.2.3.